# Using QTP/UFT's DotNetFactory.dll in VBScript

Tags: dll, vbscript, qtp, hp-uft, uft14

I am trying to use QTP/UFT's DotNetFactory utility in standalone vbs files. I believe UFT is using `DotNetFactory.dll` found in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\Unified Functional Testing\bin` to implement the feature. I have checked and found that the DLL is registered and its `ComVisible` property is also set to True. So effectively, I should be able to `CreateObject` to create an instance. However, VBScript (32-bit or 64-bit) is not able to create or get object for this dll.

[image]

None of the following is working

```
Set objDotNet = GetObject("C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\Unified Functional Testing\bin\DotNetFactory.dll")
Set objDotNet = GetObject(,"Mercury.DotNetFactory.1")
Set objDotNet = CreateObject("Mercury.QTP.Utils.DotNetFactory")
Set objDotNet = CreateObject("Mercury.DotNetFactory.1")
```

Comment: https://www.learnqtp.com/dotnetfactory-qtp-part1-basics/ suggests that you would use the command `DotNetFactory.CreateInstance("assembly.that.you.want.to.use")` in order to access the various assemblies for `.NET`

Comment: @Dave - I know how to use this in QTP. My question is related to standalone vbscript files.

Comment: Apologies, I took the question to be about using the functionality within `UFT`...

Comment: According to this answer from Motti, you can't... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986078/how-do-i-call-dotnetfactory-from-vbscript-in-a-stand-alone-vbs-file

Comment: I checked and found that UFT did expose the dll as com visible (used reflector to check) and it has prog-id (check image in question). The dll is registered as part of QTP installation. So in theory, we should be able to use it.

Comment: @PankajJaju Please do post a solution if you find one :)

Comment: @Gurman - Sure.